# Update from inserted id

Tags: postgresql

LOGIC: I want to create `loyalty_customers` when `customers.user_id` is null and update `customers.user_id` is `loyalty_customers.id`

I have a query and it's not working:

```
UPDATE customers 
SET user_id = (
    INSERT INTO loyalty_users (name) VALUES ('anonymous')) RETURNING id
)
WHERE user_id IS NULL;
```

Error like:

```
LINE 3: INSERT INTO loyalty_users
```

Look like INSERT can not be wrapped by any query, I tried this query and it's still not working:

```
SELECT id FROM (
    INSERT INTO loyalty_users (name) VALUES ('anonymous')) RETURNING id);
```

However, stand-alone INSERT query work like a charm:

```
INSERT INTO loyalty_users (name) VALUES ('anonymous')) RETURNING id;
```

Comment: It is not completely clear what your logic is, but you might want to consider a trigger which fires after `UPDATE`.

Comment: It's a migrate script so I can't use trigger here

Comment: Do you want to insert a single anonymous (and attach it every row, which is `user_id IS NULL`), or you want a separate anonymous for each `user_id IS NULL` row? (Either way, using [CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) is the simplest solution here, but can be tricky if you want a separate anomynous for each row).

Comment: Yes, I actually want a separate anonymous for each `user_id IS NULL` row. Is my code contains any danger leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the right way to do this thing is:

```
WITH updated_customer AS (
    UPDATE customers 
    SET name = 'anonymous'
    WHERE user_id IS NULL 
    RETURNING user_id AS id
)
INSERT INTO loyalty_users SELECT * FROM updated_customer;
```

It's work for me, but if you have another idea, please comment in this question.